# How to combine multiple columns into one row

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and trying to solve the following problem:

I have rows with the following columns: ID, Sequence, Name

ID can be the same if there are multiple sequences

How can I add the sequences and name and have just one row for each ID with separate columns?

Example : ID 1  Seq 1 Name Blue Seq 2 Name Green Seq 3 Name Red

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: `case` pivot on sequence number. That will handle a static/fixed number of rows. See if you have pivot operator available.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the concat option

select id || sequence as id_seq, name from table

the as clause isn't required but can help read-ability